# How to know that sql connection string is remote connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I'm using [**Microsoft Connection Dialog**](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection) in my project to retrieve a SQL Server connection string from a dialog box that shown to user.

I want limit users to only select databases from a local machine or SQL Server installed on current computer.

How to know that retrieved connection string is a remote connection and how to deny that?

Computers are located on a LAN network..

Sample connection string generated by dialog:

```
Data Source=SAEED-PC;Initial Catalog=myDB.MDF;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxx
```

Comment: why not checking if it a remote connection string , show error to user and ask him to re-enter local machine ?

Comment: What kind of an application is this.Is it windows forms or a web application. You can just get the name of the machine or server and then use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder and get the DataSource and validate it.

Comment: how can i check that? could you describe?

Comment: I'd simply check if the value of `Data Source` starts with `.` or `local` or the local machine name (which you can extract from `Environment`). Anything else could be considered a remote connection.

Comment: thank you guys..
i got that